# Memory virtualization with R on cluster

Tags: r, memory-management, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I don't know almost anything about parallel computing so this question might be very stupid and it is maybe impossible to do what I would like to.

I am using linux cluster with 40 nodes, however since I don't know how to write parallel code in R I am limited to using only one. On this node I am trying to analyse data which floods the memory (arround 64GB). So my problem isn't lack of computational power but rather memory limitation.

My question is, whether it is even possible to use some R package (like doSnow) for implicit parallelisation to use 2-3 nodes to increase the RAM limit or would I have to rewrite the script from ground to make it explicit parallelised ?

Sorry if my question is naive, any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: Writing your code in parallel will not help your RAM limitation.  Packages like ```bigmemory``` can help though.  It really depends on what your need.  Are you in a position to sample down?  Do you need to manipulate the data?  I am unsure if we have enough information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is such a package. The reason is that it would not make much sense to have one. Memory access is very fast, and accessing data from another computer over the network is very slow compared to that. So if such a package existed it would be almost useless, since the processor would need to wait for data over the network all the time, and this would make the computation very very slow.

This is true for common computing clusters, built from off-the-shelf hardware. If you happen to have a special cluster where remote memory access is fast, and is provided as a service of the operating system, then of course it might be not that bad.

Otherwise, what you need to do is to try to divide up the problem into multiple pieces, manually, and then parallelize, either using R, or another tool.

An alternative to this would be to keep some of the data on the disk, instead of loading all of it into the memory. You still need to (kind of) divide up the problem, to make sure that the part of the data in the memory is used for a reasonable amount of time for computation, before loading another part of the data.

Whether it is worth (or possible at all) doing either of these options, depends completely on your application.

Btw. a good list of high performance computing tools in R is here:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Comment: Thank you for useful explanation and link. It feels really frustrating to have whole cluster available and not to be able to use its whole power. I am using built pipeline to analyse data so unless I completely rewrite it I can't parallelise.

Answer (score 1):

For future inquiry:

You may want to have a look at two packages "snow" and "parallel".
Library "snow" extends the functionality of apply/lapply/sapply... to work on more than one core and/or one node.

Of course, you can perform simple parallel computing using more than one core:

#SBATCH --cpus-per-task= (enter some number here)

You can also perform parallel computing using more than one node (preferably with the previously mentioned libraries) using:

#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node= (enter some number here)

However, for several implications, you may wanna think of using Python instead of R where parallelism can be much more efficient using "Dask" workers.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at TidalScale, which can allow you to aggregate nodes on your cluster to run a single instance of Linux with the collective resources of the underlying nodes. www.tidalscale.com. Though the R application may be inherently single threaded, you'll be able to provide your R application with a single, simple coherent memory space across the nodes that will be transparent to your application.

Good luck with your project!